# How can I disable recyclerview particular data in Android studio?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

In database
New
Timestamp
1:aaa
Timestamp
2:bbb

This data will be read by 10 users, whenever new data came that data is visible to all users in recyclerview.

I retrieve the data with help of recyclerview.
And after the itemclick the data will be sent to another activity.

When User clicks a button, that particular recyclerview data must be  deleted only for that particular  user. All other users can read data in firebase database, that data will be shown to all users.
How can I do this, please help me out...

How can I delete data for particular user, who clicked on the activity ..

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use **SharedPreference** to store firebase data locally on user's device.
So this data can be modified for different users without affecting the Firebase data.

After storing data into **SharedPreference**, use this stored data to show in RecyclerView. And when user deletes this data, remove it from **SharedPreference**.

Use this code in **RecyclerView Adapter**
*dataList.removeAt(position)
notifyItemRemoved(position)
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, dataList.size)*

where *dataList* is the MutableList of data and *position* is the item's positon in recyclerView

Comment: Thank you so much  subodh chaudhary bro...